# How to get the Regions Sublime creates when a word is selected?

Tags: python, plugins, sublimetext2, sublimetext

When you select a word in [Sublime Text 2](http://www.sublimetext.com/), the word is highlighted and other words in the same document are outlined/boxed visually.  From what I understand all of those are called regions, but I am new to writing Sublime plugins and Python.

How do I get all of those regions in Python?  According to the [API](http://www.sublimetext.com/docs/2/api_reference.html#sublime.View), I might be able use `get_regions(key)` but I have no idea what the key might be!

I was able to make my own regions by using `find_all` with the currently selected word, but the regions are a little different than what Sublime outlines. I'd like to somehow access the built-in functionality, if possible.

[image: Selected and outlined text]

In the image, I've selected "text" and Sublime outlines all other word matches.  Basically, I want to get that RegionSet.

Comment: `key` in case of regions refers to named regions. I'm still browsing the docs as to real answer to your question.

Comment: Yeah, I'm wondering if Sublime uses a named region under-the-hood when outlining/boxing text that matches the selected.